# How to use cscope in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cscope

I am working with Visual Studio (2008 edition) for the first time. Used to programming in a Unix environment, I have become quite used to cscope and vim. For my current project, I really need cscope. I was wondering if there is any way I could use cscope on Visual Studio - or use cscope in Windows. Or if there is another tool which does this job.

Comment: What specific feature of cscope do you need? Looking at the feature list of cscope it looks like most of it is built into visual studio.

Comment: I am programming a plugin for Winamp - therefore I need to lookup functions in the Winamp SDK. (Minimum usage that I need from cscope). How to attain this in Visual Studio? For example, let's assume there is a function called DoMagic() - it is defined somewhere in the API - I don't know where. With cscope I can search all the files in the SDK for it - this is what I want to do with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You could try windows version of cscope.

As far as Visual Studio is concerned, I haven't seen anything as powerful as cscope in it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to install cscope on Windows was the `mlcscope` package in cygwin. With that, you could just [use vim with Visual Studio](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio).

As far as finding API functions in Visual Studio, you should be able to add the headers to your project so they're indexed by Intellisense.